# Linking Between PDF's

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, hyperlink

Imagine that I have two PDFs. One is a Short-Letter that is approximately 3 pages long.  The other is a Long-letter.  Short letter cites to specific paragraphs in long letter (not pages). I want to go through short letter, and put a link on top of each citation, such that when you click the link on short letter, it opens up to the correct paragraph in long letter. I have tagged each paragraph in the long-letter with a bookmark and I'm planning to manual associate the citations with the bookmarks.

What would be the best way to achieve this result? I've played around with Acrobat X's link function and I've looked into creating a binder.  However, I can't find a great solution. Ideally, I'd like to link to the bookmark in such a way that the user does not lose their spot in the short letter; either with a "return" button, by overlaying the content in some way, or by opening second document in a new window.

I've described the situation fairly specifically but this is function that would be useful frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like a need for a link annotation than a bookmark, actually.

1. Under the Content portion of your Tools menu, find the Add or Edit Interactive Object subhead and select the Link tool.
2. In your primary (short) document, click and drag the highlight around the word or sentence that you want to be your short (outbound) link to the other document. The Create Link popup should appear.
3. Make your Link Appearance choices, then select a Link Action of "Go to a page view" (not "Open a file"), then Next. A little instructional popup for Create Go to View should appear.
4. Now ignore that popup for the moment, open a new Acrobat window for your target document, and set up your display as desired for your target document, what you want your reader to see when he clicks on your link (*e.g.* Page 2, Full Page View, etc.).
5. Return to the popup and select the Set Link button.
6. Save the document.
7. You should now find that when viewing your main document and clicking on the link, Acrobat will jump to the selected page within that secondary document and display it as you specified. Clicking Alt+Left Arrow will jump back to the first document (or for convenience's sake, you might consider, say, placing a Return link annotation at the top or bottom of each page of your secondary document).